# Implementing a sandbox with custom stack on Windows 64-bit

Tags: windows, assembly, exception, sandbox, x86-64

I am currently investigating how to implement a sandbox (similar to [Google's NaCl project](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient) ) where I can run untrusted x86 code (restricted instruction set) in such a way that it cannot harm the rest of my process.

Unlike with NaCl, the untrusted code will not run in a separate process but the same process as the host application. So, one crucial step is to get Windows' structured exception handling right in order to catch errors (like invalid memory access or div by 0) and gracefully terminate the sandbox before Windows kills my host application. (NaCl doesn't face these issues. The sandbox is a separate process and simply gets killed in case of an error.)

Furthermore, the sandboxed code should not use the host applications stack but run on some separate "stack" which is allocated by myself.

Exactly this combination (exception handling in presence of a custom allocated stack) is twisting my mind. I have checked the language implementations of [Go](http://golang.org) and [Factor](http://factorcode.org/) which do similar things and with this help got something running.

But there are still some open questions and uncertainties. So I thought I'll use the fantastic knowledge of Stack Overflow to get some opinions :-)

The following is a working code snippet cut down to the core issues:

**code.cpp**

```
#include <Windows.h>
extern "C" void Sandbox();

// just a low level helper to print "msg"
extern "C" void Write(const char* msg)
{
    WriteFile(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),
              msg, (DWORD)strlen(msg), NULL, NULL);
}

// should be called first on error and continue exception handling
LONG __stdcall GlobalExceptionHandler(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS*)
{
    Write("GEH ");
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

// should be called afterwards on error and terminate the process
// of course this is just a stub to simplify the issue
// in real world it would just terminate the sandbox
extern "C" EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION __stdcall FrameExceptionHandler(
        PEXCEPTION_RECORD, ULONG64, PCONTEXT, PVOID)
{
    Write("FEH ");
    ExitProcess(42);
}

void main()
{
    AddVectoredExceptionHandler(1, GlobalExceptionHandler);
    Sandbox();
    // never reach this...
    ExitProcess(23);
}
```

**code.asm**

```
EXTERN FrameExceptionHandler:PROC
EXTERN malloc:PROC

.code

Handler:
    jmp FrameExceptionHandler

Sandbox PROC FRAME : Handler
    ; function prologue compliant with Windows x86_64 calling conventions
    ; saves rsp to the "frame-pointer" r15
    push r15
    .PUSHREG r15
    sub rsp, 20h
    .ALLOCSTACK(20h)
    mov r15, rsp
    .SETFRAME r15, 0h
    .ENDPROLOG

    ; set rsp to the top of a "heap allocated stack" of size 0x10000 bytes
    mov rcx, 10000h
    call malloc
    lea rsp, [rax+10000h]

    ; got this from implementation of the Go language runtime:
    ; while unwinding the stack, Windows sanity checks the values of
    ; RSP to be within stack-bounds. Of course RSP is set to our
    ; "heap allocated stack" and not within the bounds of what Windows
    ; thinks should be the stack.
    ; Fix this by adjusting StackBase and StackEnd in the TIB (thread
    ; information block), so that basically the stack is unbounded:
    ; StackBase = 0xffffffffffffffff, StackEnd = 0x0000000000000000
    mov rcx, 0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFh
    mov gs:[008h], rcx
    mov rcx, 0
    mov gs:[010h], rcx


    ; trigger an access error by reading invalid memory
    mov rax, 0DEADBEEFh
    mov rax, [rax]

    ; function epilogue - will never get here
    mov rax, 0
    add rsp, 28h
    ret
Sandbox ENDP

end
```

Running this will print "GEH FEH " and then gracefully exit with code 42.

Does anyone have more insight in this set `StackBase & StackEnd` "hack"?
I tried to narrow the stack limits to something like:

```
    mov gs:[008h], rsp
    mov gs:[010h], rax    ; rax is the address returned by malloc
```

But it does not work. It prints "GEH " and then crashes due to unhandled exceptions.
`FrameExceptionHandler()` will never be executed.

I also tried more relaxed boundaries that include the "heap allocated stack" as well as the stack allocated by Windows. But it doesn't help.

Another question is, whether you know any other traps I can run into. For example I noticed that Windows does not like it if RSP is uneven (I guess because you can never get to an uneven RSP by doing 2/4/8 byte PUSHes and POPs on a 16-byte aligned stack pointer).

Thanks,
Jonas

Comment: Have you played around with [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com) at all? It might be helpful if you're just needing to have a sandbox utility handy.

Comment: No, unfortunately this does not help. I am not talking about running an untrusted application in my OS, but about running untrusted x86 code within my application. E.g. a plugin for new video codec in a video player. I don't want a buggy plugin to crash my application.

Comment: [Relying on exceptions may not be good enough - IsBadXxxPtr should really be called CrashProgramRandomly](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/27/773741.aspx). Oddly enough, you can push and pop 16-bit values in 64-bit mode, while you can't do the same with 32-bit ones. If you don't want a buggy plugin to crash your process you may want to run the plugin in a separate/child process.

Comment: Hi Alexey, I know the potential pitfalls with guard pages but this will be no issue in my context. The sandboxed code will only be able to access memory which is under my control. So the only guard pages to be triggered are under my control. Running the plugin in a separate process is not an option in my setting, unfortunately :-(

Comment: Thank you for this example, this helped me figure out what was wrong with similar code I am working on here.  Note however that it totally worked for me to set the actual stack bounds to the start and end of the "sandboxed" stack space.  I had to be careful to restore the TIB fields on the way out otherwise you quickly encounter other crashes (duh)!

Comment: Hi Peter, cool that there are people out there still interested in this topic :-) I have put this aside for quite a long time, but gained interest in it again. Maybe at some time I have some more insights worth sharing here. For now just two comments: Windows will update the StackEnd field in the TIB whenever it grows the original stack (e.g. because you access the PAGE_GUARD on top of the original stack). To be more specific: save the original value with "mov rax, gs:[010h]", then overwrite it with your "sandboxed" stack bounds, and finally do a read like "mov rax, [rax-1]".

Comment: Windows will grow the stack and gs:[010h] will not be your stack bound anymore but the original stack bound minus 1 page. (I did not try it with the example given here, but in a similar case). One more nasty thing: Windows runs the exception handler on the current stack as given by RSP and it needs roughly 0x1000 bytes of stack (to my best knowledge there is nothing like sigaltstack on Linux). So if RSP is close to the "top" bound of your "sandbox" stack and you trigger any exception, your app will crash. Ouch.

Comment: I don't see how something like this could be completely fool-proof. For instance, the untrusted plugin could try to access random memory addresses. Best case, the address will be invalid and the access will be caught by your vectored exception handler, but worst case the address might actually be valid memory (heap that you allocated, data pages, code pages, etc.) and the plugin could corrupt that data.

Comment: You can handle this by restricting the memory accesses to some address range which is reserved for the plugin code only. To do this, you will have to allow all write instructions only in "safe" combinations. And you have to statically check that the plugin adheres to these restrictions. And of course, you have to compile your plugin in a special way. All this is covered by the techniques in Google's NaCl project. A very interesting piece of technology :-)

Comment: @m3tikn0b: I doubt you can perform a static analysis to ensure a compiled binary will never access an address outside a certain range. I'll also say that there is no perfect solution for this problem.

Comment: IMHO the only way to provide a foolproof sandbox for untrusted x86 code would be to run it under an emulator, then you can fully control your restricted instruction set, memory accesses, bound system calls etc.

Comment: Maybe I miss something, but why not simply use a dedicated thread for the untrusted code? If you run it from a dedicated thread then you can wrapp the thread with exception handling.

Comment: @PazO did you mean?, “I can't see why you don't wrap it in a dedicated **process**.”

Comment: @m3tikn0b I think the nativeclient project addresses this by adding special meta code along with the native code. The static analyser checks the meta code to check it is safe and treatable, then checks that the native against the meta. Then it trusts the native. However it only works for some languages and some compilers, some languages may never be supported (assembler, probably C, C++).

Answer (score 1):

Running untrusted, 3rd party code in the same process is asking for trouble. That code can kill your process in various ways. E.g. it can call `exit()` on failures, ask for lots of memory, or write to memory allocated by your threads.

The more secure yet not so hard solution is to run this code in a different process, similar to what Chrome is doing. Every Chrome extension is run in a different process and data is passed between processes.

Your application can launch a separate process and communicate with it though a pipe, windows message, shared memory (memory mapped file) for sharing large data, etc.

A plugin (usually) implements an interface so you'll need to write a proxy object to abstract the fact that the plugin resides in another process and hide the IPC complexity that comes with multi process apps. gSoap is such a framework, others exist.

Answer (score 0):

You want to execute code and check it validity. You can do it with sandbox your own. See virtual box implementation of x86 processor. It can help. 
But all virtual machines goes with price: emulating processor run underlying code 5-10 times slower than your app.

If you need only error checking and run app on core cpu, so you need to run it in thread. When thread hangs application is untouched. And you can inject some code to thread to look for it execution.
But this case is less safe, because malicious code can break your checking routines and exploit it for backdooring/rooting your system.

So, my answer: for safety - use virtual machine of you own, for speed - execute in another thread.

Best regards, and good luck
Vladimir